# Get Variations of Accent color in UWP

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

I'm trying to get a lighter variation of accent color using theme resource SystemAccentColorLight1 SystemAccentColorLight2 ...

I'm getting this exception:
The text associated with this error code could not be found.

Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key SystemAccentColorLight1 [Line: 15 Position: 19]

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ResourceKey= SystemAccentColorLight1}"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Owner.ProfileImage}" Width="50" Height="50" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"></Image>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="12" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" FontWeight="SemiBold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Owner.DisplayName}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="9" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
        </Grid>
```

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/style/color?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
>
> In XAML, the primary accent color is exposed as a theme resource named
>   SystemAccentColor. The shades are available as
>   SystemAccentColorLight3, SystemAccentColorLight2,
>   SystemAccentColorLight1, SystemAccentColorDark1,
>   SystemAccentColorDark2, and SystemAccentColorDark3. Also available
>   programmatically via UISettings.GetColorValue and the UIColorType
>   enum.

Comment: Try see this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339697/cannot-find-a-resource-with-the-name-key-phoneprogressbarbackgroundbrush

Comment: not woking, nice try

Comment: If you're using ThemeResources, make sure you put the new resource in all 3 themes - light, dark, high contrast

Comment: It Is a default Resource in UWP

Comment: If your issue is still not solved please share the xaml portion

Comment: Looks like it may depend on your SDK that you're targeting.  I am using 10.0.10240.0 and those themeresources are not in there.  Perhaps they're from a newer SDK.

Comment: I have 10.0.10586.0 version, And for me also those brushes are not available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Mark W said, the SystemAccentColorLight1 is from a newer SDK.

I test it with **Window 10 Enterprise Insider Preview** Edition and OS Build is **14316.1000**. It can get the lighter variation of accent color.

You're welcome to join the [Windows Insider Program](https://insider.windows.com/) and you can download [preview SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-developer-preview) to use this feature.

Remarks:

*Some information relates to pre-released product which may be substantially modified before it's commercially released. Microsoft makes no warranties, express or implied, with respect to the information provided here.*